# OnMouseMove on body tag causing issues with child dropdown elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using on mousemove property on body tag as :

```
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
</body>
```

I am using this for resetting use's login session. This works fine, until when i add a dropdown inside this body tag inside a div, it is causing issues. 
Whenever I am trying to select value from dropdown, It just goes away since I am moving the cursor and resetTimers() is triggered.

Can some body help me how to avoid this issue.

Thanks

```
var timoutWarning = 900000; 
var timoutNow = 1200000;


var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartTimers();
    $("#dialog").dialog().dialog('close');
}


function IdleWarning() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        title:'Alert'
    });
}

function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location.href = 'Logoff';
}
```

ANSWER:

```
$("#dialog").dialog().dialog('close');
```

caused jquery issue. Because of this everything is messed up. I have changed this to close dialog when user click "OK" button on the alert screen.LIKE:

```
function IdleWarning() {
    $("#dialog").text('Your session will be closed in 5 minutes due to inactivity. Click OK to continue.').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        title:'Alert'
        ,buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                ResetTimers();
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The errors are on the call to setTimeout. They should be warningTimer = setTimeout(IdleWarning, timoutWarning); and timeoutTimer = setTimeout(IdleTimeout, timoutNow);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're letting the `mousemove` event bubble up to the `body` element. Add an event handler for `mousemove` for the `select` element and use the stopPropagation() method to stop the event from bubbling up. Try this (assuming you may have more than one select).

```
$('select').mousemove(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

That should stop the problem.